# Stacked Bar and Bar chart in a Single Chart

Tags: python, plotly, bar-chart

Hi I trying to build a stacked bar and a bar to be in a single chart.
But the last element of the stacked chart plan["Not Capable"] is not stacking correctly.
Can anyone enlighten me what is wrong ?

```
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bar_chart1 = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name="Actual Implemented",
            x=plan["Month"],
            y=plan["Actual Implemented"],
            offsetgroup=0,
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Acc Plan",
            x=plan["Month"],
            y=plan["Acc Plan"],
            offsetgroup=1,
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Not Automated ",
            x=plan["Month"],
            y=plan["Not Automated "],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=plan["Acc Plan"],
           
        ),

          go.Bar(
            name="Not Capable",
            x=plan["Month"],
            y=plan["Not Capable "],
            offsetgroup=1,
            base=(plan["Not Automated "])
        ),

    ],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Issue Types - Original and Models",
        yaxis_title="Number of Issues",
        
    )
)
bar_chart1.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy8hG.png)

Comment: `fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')` You didn't want this designation?

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't tell exactly what you're going for per your description, it appears you should reexamine your  use of the offsetgroup property.

If you want all items stacked together, use the same value for offsetgroup.

```
bar_chart1 = go.Figure(
    data=[
        go.Bar(
            name="Actual Implemented",
            x=plan["Month"],
            y=plan["Actual Implemented"],
            offsetgroup=0,
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Acc Plan",
            x=plan["Month"],
            y=plan["Acc Plan"],
            offsetgroup=0,
        ),
        go.Bar(
            name="Not Automated ",
            x=plan["Month"],
            y=plan["Not Automated "],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=plan["Acc Plan"],
           
        ),

          go.Bar(
            name="Not Capable",
            x=plan["Month"],
            y=plan["Not Capable "],
            offsetgroup=0,
            base=(plan["Not Automated "])
        ),

    ],
    layout=go.Layout(
        title="Issue Types - Original and Models",
        yaxis_title="Number of Issues",
        
    )
)
bar_chart1.show()
```